# MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495' while intend to put many messages

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I intend to use following code to send many messages into IBM MQ

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
        MQEnvironment.hostname = "192.168.0.13";
        MQEnvironment.port = 1414;
        MQEnvironment.channel = "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN";
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(CMQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, CMQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);

        MQQueueManager qMgr;
        MQMessage tmpMsg = new MQMessage();
        try {
            qMgr = new MQQueueManager("QM1");
            MQQueue destQueue = qMgr.accessQueue("TESTQ", openOptions);

            tmpMsg.write("Msg1".getBytes());
            destQueue.put(tmpMsg, pmo);
            tmpMsg.clearMessage();

            tmpMsg.write("Msg2".getBytes());
            destQueue.put(tmpMsg, pmo);

            destQueue.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          if(qMgr != null)
            qMgr.disconnect();
        }

    }
```

then the program give me error `MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495'`. I saw the other post said something about that I have set this program to connect in binding mode? I didn't see anything about binding in my `openOptions`. Does anyone know what happen?

=====Update=====

the client that I'm using is `com.ibm.mq.allclient 9.3.2.0`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What version of MQ are the jar files from? What is the full stack of the error? If it mentions libmqjbnd it is likely not an actual error.

Answer (score 2):

What is the exact version/release number of the MQ JAR files you are using? i.e. 9.2.0.11

This could be a bug in the Java/MQ library or a simple coding issue on your part.

You should only ever get Reason Code 2495 - MQRC_MODULE_NOT_FOUND when your client application is connecting in "bindings mode" but by your code above, you appear to be connecting to the queue manager in "client mode". Which does appear to be correct.

Here are some of the problems I see with your code:

- MQEnvironment class is not thread-safe and should not be used. You should set the connection parameters in a Hashtable and pass it to the MQQueueManager class.
- You should never use any MQ object that begins with 'SYSTEM' (i.e. SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN). Create your own channel for your application. i.e. APP.TEST.CHL or whatever you want to call it.
- You should have a catch clause for the MQException and then dump out the MQ Completion Code and Reason Code.
- The close method for the opened queue should be in the finally clause.

Here's my suggestion on what the code should look like:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;

public class SO_TestIt
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
      Hashtable<String,Object> mqht = new Hashtable<String,Object>();

      mqht.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "APP.TEST.CHL");
      mqht.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "192.168.0.13");
      mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(1414));
      mqht.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "myUserId");
      mqht.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "myPwd");

      MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
      MQQueue        destQueue = null;
      MQMessage      tmpMsg = new MQMessage();
      try {
          qMgr = new MQQueueManager("QM1", mqht);
          destQueue = qMgr.accessQueue("TESTQ", openOptions);

          tmpMsg.write("Msg1".getBytes());
          destQueue.put(tmpMsg, new MQPutMessageOptions());
          tmpMsg.clearMessage();

          tmpMsg.write("Msg2".getBytes());
          destQueue.put(tmpMsg, new MQPutMessageOptions());
      } catch (MQException e) {
          System.err.println("Put CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         try {
            if(destQueue != null)
               destQueue.close();
         } catch (MQException e) {
            System.err.println("Close: CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
         }

         try {
            if(qMgr != null)
               qMgr.disconnect();
         } catch (MQException e) {
            System.err.println("Disconnect: CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: the version of client is 9.3.2.0

Comment: about the channel, it will be changed in sit environment. right now i'm just testing it on dev environment

Comment: Start in DEV doing the right thing by having your own channel.  Did you also include the JSON JAR in your CLASSPATH because it is required for IBM MQ v9.1 or higher?  Finally, I just ran the code I posted against MQ JARs from 9.3.2.0, and it worked fine.  Did you try my code?